# jQuery - extending objects while ensuring integrity of array members

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin using a typical `$.extend` scenario for merging user settings with the defaults, as in:

```
var settings = $.extend({
      title: '',
      padding: [0,0,0,0]
    }, options);
```

Is there a swift way to ensure that `padding` always be a 4-member array of integers, honouring user's proper parameters, but ignoring/sanitizing bad type parameters?

Comment: No, you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: you will have to write all that verification yourself. One suggestion would be test it for conditions you want , if it doesn't pass log an error to console for developer to know it's not correct

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to check validity of `options` before extending the defaults. so no 'swift way' there.

I would however go for four separate properties to make the code more readable (which index is which padding; top, left, right, bottom?) and solve your problem...

```
var settings = $.extend({
    title: '',
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
}, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following code, which so far has worked just fine:

```
if (options.padding && $.isArray(options.padding)) {
  var pd = options.padding;
  // Parsing shortcuts.
  switch (pd.length) {
    case 0:
      options.padding = [0,0,0,0];
      break;
    case 1:
      options.padding = [pd[0], pd[0], pd[0], pd[0]];
      break;
    case 2:
      options.padding = [pd[0], pd[1], pd[0], pd[1]];
      break;
    case 3:
      options.padding = [pd[0], pd[1], pd[2], pd[1]];
      break;
    default:
      options.padding = pd.splice(0, 4);
  }

  // Sanitizing values.
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var pv = options.padding[i];
    switch (typeof pv) {
      case 'number':
        options.padding[i] = Math.floor(pv);
        break;
      default:
        options.padding[i] = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
} else {
  delete options.padding;
}
```

Comment: Or you can use `with` if you don't want to type all the `options`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vrRGp/ (Note: Normally you shouldn't use `with`, just saying)

Comment: That is a awful lot of code for just padding options. Be careful not to make code which is "write only"...